# Excel IF with DATEDIF, when Date is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

Assistance with this formula. If the date cell is blank, leave blank, otherwise if the date is less than today, give the difference in months:

```
=IF(F5="","",(F5<TODAY(),DATEDIF(F5,TODAY(),"M")))
```

Comment: You are missing the inner `IF()`

Comment: Can you show me which IF() I'm missing: =IF(F5="","",(F5<TODAY(),DATEDIF(F5,TODAY(),"M")))

Comment: what if it is greater than or equal to today?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny mistake there.

```
=IF(F5="","",IF(F5<TODAY(),DATEDIF(F5,TODAY(),"M")))
```

Tell me to know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked.  Really appreciate!!

Comment: can you mark my answer as the "correct answer" by the tickmark on the left side?